# obtaining all the previous values of a variable

Tags: python, variables

i made a shopping program and Im trying to obtain the value of the quantity inserted with the corresponding product but it only prints the last inputted value and overwrite all of the previous values

```
final_option, total_quantity, total_cost, total = 0, 0, 0, 0

cart = []
while continue_order != 0:
    option = int(input("Which item would you like to purchase?: "))
    cart.append(option)
    if option >= 10:
        print('we do not serve that here')

    elif option == 1:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: ₹" + str(total))
    elif option == 2:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 3:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 60
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 4:
        qquantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 180
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 5:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 6:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 90
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 7:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 150
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 8:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 9:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 120
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    elif option == 10:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * 200
        print("The price is: " + str(total))
    total_cost += total
    continue_order = int(input("Would you like another item? enter Yes--> (1) or--> No (0):"))

print("Your receipt:\n")
for option in cart :
    print("Menu item number: ", option, "Quantity",quantity)

print("Total Price: ", total_cost)
```

eg if i chose to buy a burger of 7 units and a pizza of 3 units the bill comes out like
burger , quantity: 3
pizza , quantity: 3
the pizza's quantity value overwrites the burgers , how can i get the correct corresponding value of the inserted quantity with the product

Comment: You need to add the quantities to a list, preferably by storing (option, quantity) tuples in the `cart` list.

Comment: For future expansion, don't use a huge `if/elif/elif` sequence for this.  Instead, create a data structure that has the price for each item.  I'll show you below.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I'm storing the prices in a list.  You could also store the item name in that last as well, if that comes up.

```
total_cost = 0

prices = [150, 120, 60, 180, 150, 90, 150, 120, 120, 200]

cart = []
while True:
    option = int(input("Which item would you like to purchase?: "))
    if option > len(prices):
        print('we do not serve that here')
    else:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        total = quantity * prices[option-1]
        print("The price is:", total)
        cart.append( (option, quantity) )
        total_cost += total

    if input("Would you like another item? enter Yes--> (1) or--> No (0):") == '0':
        break

print("Your receipt:\n")
for option,quantity in cart :
    print("Menu item number: ", option, "Quantity",quantity)

print("Total Price: ", total_cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take @tim-roberts solution (which I upvoted) one step farther and base my menu items on a dictionary. This would allow you to add things like a description fairly easily.

```
products = {
    "1": {"id": "1", "cost": 150},
    "2": {"id": "2", "cost": 120},
    "3": {"id": "3", "cost": 60},
    "4": {"id": "4", "cost": 180},
    "5": {"id": "5", "cost": 150},
    "6": {"id": "6", "cost": 90},
    "7": {"id": "7", "cost": 150},
    "8": {"id": "8", "cost": 120},
    "9": {"id": "9", "cost": 120},
    "10": {"id": "10", "cost": 200}
}

cart = []
while True:
    product_id = input("Which item would you like to purchase?: ")
    product = products.get(product_id)
    if product:
        quantity = int(input("Enter the quantity: "))
        cart.append({
            "id": product["id"],
            "quantity": quantity,
            "total": quantity * product["cost"]
        })
        print(f"\tYou requested {quantity} items at ${product['cost']} per item.")
    else:
        print('Sorry, we do not serve that here.')

    continue_order = input("Would you like another item? Enter Yes--> (1) or--> No (0): ")
    if continue_order == "0":
        break

print("\nYour receipt:")
for product in cart :
    print(f"\tMenu Item: {product['id']} Quantity: {product['quantity']} Total: {product['total']}")

cart_total = sum(p["total"] for p in cart)
print(f"\tTotal Price: ${cart_total}")
```